# listbox selected values (winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

Hi how to display seleted item values in multi selected listbox using winforms.

can somebody give me a sample code snippet?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Does [`ListBox.SelectedItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems.aspx) not do what you want?

```
for (object x in listBox.SelectedItems)
{
    // Do something with the selected item
}
```

You can also use [`ListBox.SelectedIndices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindices.aspx).

Comment: i want to display one by one value in listbox (selected values only)

Comment: @Nagu: And what problem are you running into?

Comment: i want to display the value of list box selected value

Comment: @Nagu: Right, so I've given an example which gives you the selected value... what problem are you having?